# Python Turtle: the cursor is not moving

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a problem with my uni project's code, especially in the turtle module section. This program displays student marks and we are supposed to show a bar chart using the turtle module. The problem I am encountering is that even though the turtle workspace shows up, the cursor is not moving to draw the bar chart.

This is the code:

```
def menu():

    allStudentsMarks = {}

    while True:
        userinput = input("Enter 1 to store student details \n"+
                  "Enter 2 to display student report \n"+
                  "Enter 3 to exit \n")
        if userinput == "1":
            enterMarks(allStudentsMarks)
        elif userinput == "2":
            displayReports(allStudentsMarks)
        elif userinput == "3":
            print("You have left the program. Thank you.")
            break

def enterMarks(allStudentsMarks):
    studentName = input("Please enter the student's name: ")

    while True:
        DFMarks = input("Please enter the marks from 0-20: ")
        DFMarks = float(DFMarks)
        if DFMarks >= 0 and DFMarks <= 20:
            break

    while True:
        ProjectMarks = input("Please enter the marks from 0-30: ")
        ProjectMarks = float(ProjectMarks)
        if ProjectMarks >= 0 and ProjectMarks <= 30:
            break

    while True:
        FinalMarks = input("Please enter the marks from 0-50: ")
        FinalMarks = float(FinalMarks)
        if FinalMarks >= 0 and FinalMarks <= 50:
            break

    marksList = [DFMarks, ProjectMarks, FinalMarks]
    allStudentsMarks[studentName] = marksList
    studentDetails = sum(marksList)

def getBelowAvgDFMarks(studentDetails):
    marks = list(studentDetails.values())
    dfTot = 0
    dfLen = 0
    for marksList in marks:
        dfTot += marksList[0]
        dfLen += 1
    dfAvg = dfTot / dfLen
    print("Displaying the student(s) whose DF marks are below the average of", dfAvg)

    belowAvgDF = {}
    for student in studentDetails:
        if studentDetails[student][0] < dfAvg:
                belowAvgDF[student] = studentDetails[student][0]
    print(belowAvgDF)
    return

def getBelowAvgProjectMarks(studentDetails):
    marks = list(studentDetails.values())
    projectTot = 0
    projectLen = 0
    for marksList in marks:
        projectTot = projectTot + marksList[1]
        projectLen = projectLen + 1
    projectAvg = projectTot / projectLen
    print("Displaying the student(s) whose project marks are below the average of", projectAvg)

    belowAvgProject = {}
    for student in studentDetails:
        if studentDetails[student][1] < projectAvg:
            belowAvgProject[student] = studentDetails[student][1]
    print(belowAvgProject)
    return

def getBelowAvgFinalExamMarks(studentDetails):
    marks = list(studentDetails.values())
    finalTot = 0
    finalLen = 0
    for marksList in marks:
        finalTot = finalTot + marksList[2]
        finalLen = finalLen + 1
    finalAvg = finalTot / finalLen
    print("Displaying the student(s) whose final marks are below the average of", finalAvg)

    belowAvgFinal = {}
    for student in studentDetails:
        if studentDetails[student][2] < finalAvg:
            belowAvgFinal[student] = studentDetails[student][2]
    print(belowAvgFinal)
    return

def getBelowAvgOverallMarks(studentDetails):
    marks = list(studentDetails.values())
    overall = 0
    overallLen = len(marks)
    for marksList in marks:
        for num in marksList:
            overall += num
    overallAvg = overall / overallLen
    print(overallAvg)
    print("Displaying the student(s) whose overall marks are below the average of", overallAvg)

    belowAvgOverall = {}
    for student in studentDetails:
        if sum(studentDetails[student]) < overallAvg:
            belowAvgOverall[student] = sum(studentDetails[student])
    print(belowAvgOverall)
    return

def getTotalMarks(studentDetails):
    total = []
    marks = list(studentDetails.values())
    total = 0
    for i in marks:
        for num in i:
            total = total + num
        print(total)
        total = 0

    import turtle
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    turtle.color("blue", "lightblue")
    for marks in range(total):
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(10)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(marks)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(10)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(marks)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(20)

    wn.exitonclick()


def displayReports(allStudentsDetails): 
    userinput = input("Enter 1 to get the average DF report marks \n"+
                   "Enter 2 to get the average project report marks \n"+
                   "Enter 3 to get the average final exam marks \n"+
                   "Enter 4 to get the overall marks \n"+
                   "Enter 5 to get the selected student marks \n"+
                  "Enter 6 to get the bar chart of the total marks \n")
    if userinput == "1":
        getBelowAvgDFMarks(allStudentsDetails)
    elif userinput == "2":
        getBelowAvgProjectMarks(allStudentsDetails)
    elif userinput == "3":
        getBelowAvgFinalExamMarks(allStudentsDetails)
    elif userinput == "4":
        getBelowAvgOverallMarks(allStudentsDetails)
    elif userinput == "5":
        displaySelectedStudentsMarks(allStudentsDetails)
    elif userinput == "6":
        getTotalMarks(allStudentsDetails)
        return

def displaySelectedStudentsMarks(selectedStudentsDetails):
    for studentNameKey in selectedStudentsDetails:
        displayAStudentsDetail(studentNameKey, selectedStudentsDetails[studentNameKey])

def displayAStudentsDetail(studentName, studentMarkList):
    print("Student name: ", studentName)
    print("DF marks: ", studentMarkList[0], "\tProject marks: ", studentMarkList[1], "\tFinal exam: ", studentMarkList[2], "\tTotal marks: ", sum(studentMarkList))


menu()
```

When you input the value '6' ("get the bar chart of the total marks"), in the second level "display student report" menu, it should be able to show the bar chart with the value of total exam for each student.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `getTotalMarks()` is a total mess.  Not so much turtle-wise but Python-wise.  One clue is that you have two different variables with the same name:

```
total = []
marks = list(studentDetails.values())
total = 0
```

I'm going to suggest three changes.  First, import turtle this way:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
```

Second, start up your `menu()` routine this way:

```
wn = Screen()

menu()

wn.exitonclick()
```

I.e. don't put `exitonclick()` inside a function, make it the last thing your code does.  Finally, replace `getTotalMarks()` with this rewrite:

```
def getTotalMarks(studentDetails):
    totals = [sum(scores) for scores in studentDetails.values()]

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.color("blue", "lightblue")

    for total in totals:
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(10)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(total)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(10)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(total)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.forward(20)
```

It's nothing fancy, but it should get you moving forward.